# Asp.Net code first role provider stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, roles

I am using code first with Entity Framework 6 and MVC 5.1 in Visual Studio 2013.  Without making any changes to the web.config, model classes, or anything directly relating to Roles my app lost the ability to determine a User's Role membership.  In fact most of the project is boilerplate MVC.  I was purposefully trying to keep it as simple as possible.  Nothing fancy.

Authentication works and **System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity** is populated appropriately.

Outputting **string.Join(",", Roles.GetRolesForUser())** shows that the user, though logged in, belongs to no roles.

Double checking the AspNetRoles, AspNetUsers, and AspNetUserRoles shows that the user is  associated with a number of different roles.

Not more than 24 hours ago all role specific features were working appropriately so I at least know that everything had been correctly configured at some point.

Short of posting my entire project it is impossible to list all the factors but I was hoping others may have had a similar experience and provide possible solutions.

Comment: You might want to start using some form of version control, so you can go back and look at the changes you've made over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the Code First role provider needs lazy-loading enabled.  I had disabled lazy-loading earlier.  **base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;**.  The role provider began working as soon as I enabled this feature.